# implicit super-interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface

So we all know that all classes implicitly extend Object. How about interfaces? Is there an implicit super-interface? I say there is. The following code compiles:

```
java.io.Serializable s1 = null;
java.io.Serializable s2 = null;

s1.equals(s2);
```

The `equals` method is not declared in Serializable, but in Object. Since interfaces can only extend other interfaces, and Object is a class, not an interface, there must be some implicit interface that is being extended. And the `Object` class must then implicitly implement this implicit interface (wow, that was weird to write).

So, the question is, how correct is this?

Comment: I don't get your contention that "there must be some implicit interface that is being extended".  How do you get to that conclusion from what we see here?

Comment: As a side note, this code will throw a NullPointerException rather than working.

Comment: I never said it would run. I specifically said only that it would compile.

Comment: Not correct at all.  You'll find no mention of a super interface in the JLS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Since interfaces can only extend other
>   interfaces, and Object is a class, not
>   an interface, there must be some
>   implicit interface that is being
>   extended.

No. Citing the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.4.4):

> If an interface has no direct
>   superinterfaces, then **the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract
>   member method** m with signature s,
>   return type r, and throws clause t
>   **corresponding to each public instance
>   method** m with signature s, return type
>   r, and throws clause t **declared in
>   Object**, unless a method with the same
>   signature, same return type, and a
>   compatible throws clause is explicitly
>   declared by the interface. It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly 
>   declares such a method m in the case
>   where m is declared to be final in
>   Object.

The difference between this and your "implicit super interface" is that `Object` has a number of final and protected methods, and you couldn't have those modifiers in an interface.

Answer (score 7):

s1 and s2 here are object references, referring to instances of objects that implement Serializable.  There is no such thing as an interface reference in Java.

So Java knows that whatever these objects are, they descend from java.lang.Object.  Hence the above code is valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare something like:

```
java.io.Serializable s1 = null;
```

don't forget that everything in Java is derived from `Object`.  So here, you are only saying that `s1` is **something** (either `Object` or some class extending `Object`) that `implements Serializable`. There is no magic.  Everything in Java is derived from `Object` whether it is explicit or not.  Thus, the `equals` method is always available.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but how is declaring a variable "declaring a type"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any super interface.

When you declare a variable like this:

```
java.io.Serializable s1 = null;
```

you haven't created any `Object`.

The compiler knows that `s1` and `s2` will implement `Serializable` and will descend from `Object` so it allows the `equals`.