# trying to understand implicit superinterfaces

Tags: java

Sorry to bring back the [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803466/implicit-super-interface-in-java). But I still don't clearly understand what this section of specification states.

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature
>   s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public
>   instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t
>   declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface. It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly
>   declares such a method m in the case where m is declared to be final
>   in Object.

Given

```
interface Testing
{
    void test();
}
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t = new Testing(){
            @Override
            public void test(){
            }
        };
        t.test();
        t.toString();
    }
}
```

Now as the spec states that the above will change to

```
    interface Testing
    {
        void test();
        String toString();
        //other non-final methods of Object
    }
    public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Testing t = new Testing(){
                @Override
                public void test(){
                }
            };
            t.test();
            t.toString(); 
        }
    }
```

Also. please confirm if there is an hierarchy of interfaces then all of them get these abstract methods.

Comment: what exactly is your question? every class inherits the methods of Object regardless of the implemented interfaces

Comment: my question is - "is my understanding correct?" Also "what is the necessity of this?"

Comment: yes your understanding is correct.As long as you have a method in interface either explicitly or implicitly. It doesn't matter to other classes or interfaces that use them

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that every class extends Object (at some point in its class heirarchy). However, interfaces do not extend Object. This is to avoid the problems that arise from multiple inheirtance.

Since interfaces do not extend `Object` that would mean we were unable to use methods like `toString` if the type (not class) of the object we had access to was an interface. But we know those methods must be available since all classes at some point extend from `Object`. Therefore, to get around this problem all of `Object`'s not final methods are implicitly declared in all interfaces that have no superinterfaces. These contracts of these methods are always satisfied since all classes must at some point extend from `Object`.

TL;DR -- it's a trick to make sure we can access the methods made available by `Object` when we have an instance of some class stored in variable that's type is an interface (eg. `Serializable`)

edit: To answer your question, You're slightly off. All non-final methods of `Object` are added to an interface (whether they are used or not) if that interface has no parent interface AND for each method to added: that there is no matching method is explicitly declared by the interface.

Comment: I thought OP's question was `please confirm if there is an hierarchy of interfaces then all of them get these abstract methods` this? Did i miss something?

Comment: @sasidhar: thats my second question

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no super interface to an interface it gets the implicit declaration of the Object class methods. As long as these methods are included in the interface. Every interface that either extends or implements this interface doesn't see much difference between the methods that are explicitly declared by this interface or it got implicitly. That point forward that interface is as good as declared them explicitly.