# Is there any super interface of all interfaces in Java?

Tags: java

As we have Object class as super class of all the classes. So do we also have super Interface of all the interfaces?

Comment: What would be the purpose of such an interface? You can already use `Object` to accept an object of any type. It might be best that you expand the question with your use case.

Comment: Any instance of any interface must be an instance of `Object`. So essentially it's still `Object`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the super class for all the interfaces in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451297/what-is-the-super-class-for-all-the-interfaces-in-java). Also [implicit super-interface in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803466/implicit-super-interface-in-java)

Comment: We have ```Object``` class as super class of all the classes, interfaces and enums.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not an ultimate super Interface that all Java interfaces inherit from. If you follow the links in the javadoc under **All Superinterfaces** for some common interfaces, you'll see that they don't all end up in the same place.  For example, [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) have no superinterface at all, so there isn't one that all interfaces have in common.